# Alert didn't work in Chrome driver

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using website where i have certificate popup in all browsers i handle the popup with alert code example:

```
            try
            {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                if (alert != null)
                {
                    alert.Accept();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }
```

But when i'm using chrome driver it's didn't catch the alert and throw an exception:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:65505/session/3c3a49f5ea328ffff6cc44effaa8326f/alert_text
>   timed out after 60 seconds.

**The popup image:**

[image]

It's not part of web html code, so what i'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is an alert, not a frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the below code snippet a try :

```
driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"{ENTER}");
```